# Can someone help me with this message?

Tags: c, function, variables, struct

I'm writing a program in C and declared the following structure:

```
   typedef struct
   {
     int type[4][4];
     int color;
   } block;
```

So, I wrote the following function to initialize the variables:

```
     void inicialize(block aux[1])
     {
       aux[0].type[4][4] = {
                               {0, 0, 0, 0},
                               {1, 2, 0, 2},
                               {3, 2, 0, 0},
                               {0, 0, 0, 0}
                           };
     }
```

But when I compile the program, I got the following message:

```
C:\ncurses\tetris.c|11|error: expected expression before '{' token|
```

Please, I need to finalize this program. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please change your title to be more descriptive.

Comment: BTW, I'm sure this very error has been addressed endless times here already. (Unfortunately, you are not the only one who refuse to learn the basics of the language before using it.)

Comment: `inicialize` should that be `initialize`? Anyway 11 - Then where is line 11?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void inicialize(block aux[1]){
    memcpy(aux[0].type,
        (int [4][4]){
                        {0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {1, 2, 0, 2},
                        {3, 2, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0}
                     },
        sizeof(aux[0].type));
}
```

Comment: Interesting code.just was curious.could you check this for me I tried this       #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct def{
    int type[4][4];
    int colour;
};
int main(void){
    
    struct def array[1];
    
    memcpy(array[1].type,(int [4][4]){
        {0, 0, 0, 0},
        {1, 2, 0, 2},
        {3, 2, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
    },sizeof(array[0].type));

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            printf("%d  ",array[0].type[i][j]);
    return 0;
}

Comment: +1 @BLUEPIXY thanks, it works on the link,but my compiler gives some errors. I should look into it. but I like your code.

Answer (score 0):

> So, I wrote the following function to initialize the variables:

No, you didn't. That's not initialization, that's an assignment, and you can't assign arrays. Either **really initialize** the variable, or fill the array elements one by one, or initialize an array and `memcpy()`, or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

You are using initialization syntax in an assignment. And that's not allowed.

You could just assign the values you need to the variable. Or you could define a constant using the initialization syntax, and assign that constant to the variable.

The latter looks like this:

```
const int initialBlock[4][4] = { ... };
```

And then you can assign like this:

```
aux[0].type = initialBlock;
```

It's also a little odd that you pass an array of block of length one to your function. It would be more usual to pass the address of a single struct.